# My eight braille pattern progressive snake spinner

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, graphical-output, animation

### Introduction

I would like to drawn a nice *spinner* by using eight braille patterns on two lines, drawing a square of 8x8 ***pixel***, for showing a kind of *snake* growing and reducing:

```
declare -a shapes=([0]=$'\E[A⠁⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1]=$'\E[A⠈⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [2]=$'\E[A⠀⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [3]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [4]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [5]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [6]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠁\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [7]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠈\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [8]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠐\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [9]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠠\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [10]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [11]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [12]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠐' [13]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠠' [14]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢀' [15]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⡀' [16]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⠀' [17]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⡀⠀' [18]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⠀⠀' [19]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⡀⠀⠀' [20]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⢀⠀⠀⠀' [21]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡀⠀⠀⠀' [22]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠄⠀⠀⠀' [23]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠂⠀⠀⠀' [24]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [25]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [26]=$'\E[A⠄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [27]=$'\E[A⠂⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [28]=$'\E[A⠁⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [29]=$'\E[A⠉⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [30]=$'\E[A⠈⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [31]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [32]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [33]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [34]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⠁\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [35]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠉\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [36]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠘\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [37]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠰\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [38]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [39]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [40]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [41]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠰' [42]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢠' [43]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣀' [44]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⡀' [45]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⠀' [46]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⡀⠀' [47]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⠀⠀' [48]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⢀⡀⠀⠀' 
  [49]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣀⠀⠀⠀' [50]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡄⠀⠀⠀' [51]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠆⠀⠀⠀' [52]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [53]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [54]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [55]=$'\E[A⠆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [56]=$'\E[A⠃⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [57]=$'\E[A⠉⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [58]=$'\E[A⠉⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [59]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [60]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [61]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [62]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [63]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⠉\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [64]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠙\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [65]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠸\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [66]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [67]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [68]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [69]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [70]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢰' [71]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣠' [72]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣀' [73]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⡀' [74]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⠀' [75]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⡀⠀' [76]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⠀⠀' [77]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣀⡀⠀⠀' [78]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣄⠀⠀⠀' [79]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡆⠀⠀⠀' [80]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [81]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [82]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [83]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [84]=$'\E[A⠇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [85]=$'\E[A⠋⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [86]=$'\E[A⠉⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [87]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [88]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [89]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [90]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [91]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [92]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⠙\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [93]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [94]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [95]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [96]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [97]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [98]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' 
  [99]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣰' [100]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣠' [101]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣀' [102]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⡀' [103]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⠀' [104]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⡀⠀' [105]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⠀⠀' [106]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣄⡀⠀⠀' [107]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣆⠀⠀⠀' [108]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [109]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [110]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [111]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [112]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [113]=$'\E[A⠏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [114]=$'\E[A⠋⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [115]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [116]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [117]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [118]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [119]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [120]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [121]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⠹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [122]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [123]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [124]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [125]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [126]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [127]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [128]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣰' [129]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣠' [130]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣀' [131]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⡀' [132]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⠀' [133]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⡀⠀' [134]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⠀⠀' [135]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣆⡀⠀⠀' [136]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [137]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [138]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [139]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [140]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [141]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [142]=$'\E[A⠏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [143]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [144]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [145]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [146]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' 
  [147]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [148]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [149]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [150]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [151]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [152]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [153]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [154]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [155]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [156]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [157]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣰' [158]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣠' [159]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣀' [160]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⡀' [161]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⠀' [162]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⡀⠀' [163]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⠀⠀' [164]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [165]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [166]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [167]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [168]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [169]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [170]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [171]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [172]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [173]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [174]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [175]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [176]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [177]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [178]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [179]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [180]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [181]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [182]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [183]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [184]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [185]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [186]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣰' [187]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣠' [188]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣀' [189]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⡀' [190]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⠀' [191]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⡀⠀' [192]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [193]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [194]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' 
  [195]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [196]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [197]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [198]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [199]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [200]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [201]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [202]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [203]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [204]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [205]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [206]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [207]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [208]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [209]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [210]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [211]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [212]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [213]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [214]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [215]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣰' [216]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣠' [217]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣀' [218]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⡀' [219]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⠀' [220]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [221]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [222]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [223]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [224]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [225]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [226]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [227]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [228]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [229]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [230]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [231]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [232]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [233]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [234]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [235]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [236]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [237]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [238]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [239]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [240]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [241]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [242]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' 
  [243]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [244]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣰' [245]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣠' [246]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣀' [247]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⡀' [248]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [249]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [250]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [251]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [252]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [253]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [254]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [255]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [256]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [257]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [258]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [259]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [260]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [261]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [262]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [263]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [264]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [265]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [266]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [267]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [268]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [269]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [270]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [271]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [272]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [273]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣰' [274]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣠' [275]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣀' [276]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [277]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [278]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [279]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [280]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [281]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [282]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [283]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [284]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [285]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [286]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [287]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [288]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [289]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [290]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' 
  [291]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [292]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [293]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [294]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [295]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [296]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [297]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [298]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [299]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [300]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [301]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [302]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣰' [303]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣠' [304]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [305]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [306]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [307]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [308]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [309]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [310]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [311]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [312]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [313]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [314]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [315]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [316]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [317]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [318]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [319]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [320]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [321]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [322]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [323]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [324]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [325]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [326]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [327]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [328]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [329]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [330]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [331]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣰' [332]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [333]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [334]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [335]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [336]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [337]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [338]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' 
  [339]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [340]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [341]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [342]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [343]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [344]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [345]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [346]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [347]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [348]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [349]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [350]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [351]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [352]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [353]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [354]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [355]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [356]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [357]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [358]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [359]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [360]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [361]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [362]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [363]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [364]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [365]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [366]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [367]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [368]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [369]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [370]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [371]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [372]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [373]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [374]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [375]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [376]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [377]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [378]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [379]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [380]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [381]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [382]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [383]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [384]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [385]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [386]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' 
  [387]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [388]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [389]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [390]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [391]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [392]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [393]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [394]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [395]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [396]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [397]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [398]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [399]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [400]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [401]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [402]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [403]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [404]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [405]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [406]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [407]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [408]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [409]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [410]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [411]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [412]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [413]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [414]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [415]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [416]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [417]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [418]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [419]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [420]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [421]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [422]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [423]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [424]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [425]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [426]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [427]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [428]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [429]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [430]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [431]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [432]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [433]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [434]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' 
  [435]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [436]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [437]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [438]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [439]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [440]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [441]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [442]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [443]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [444]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [445]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [446]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [447]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [448]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [449]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [450]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [451]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [452]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [453]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [454]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [455]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [456]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [457]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [458]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [459]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠈' [460]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [461]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [462]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [463]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [464]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [465]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [466]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [467]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [468]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [469]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [470]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [471]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [472]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [473]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [474]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [475]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [476]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [477]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [478]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [479]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [480]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [481]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [482]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' 
  [483]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [484]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [485]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [486]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [487]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠈' [488]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠘' [489]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [490]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [491]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [492]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [493]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [494]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [495]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [496]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [497]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [498]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [499]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [500]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [501]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [502]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [503]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [504]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [505]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [506]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [507]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [508]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [509]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [510]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [511]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [512]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [513]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [514]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [515]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠈' [516]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠘' [517]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠸' [518]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [519]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [520]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [521]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [522]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [523]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [524]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [525]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [526]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [527]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [528]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [529]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [530]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' 
  [531]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [532]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [533]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [534]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [535]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [536]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [537]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [538]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [539]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [540]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [541]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [542]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [543]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠈' [544]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠘' [545]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠸' [546]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⢸' [547]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [548]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [549]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [550]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [551]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [552]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [553]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [554]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [555]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [556]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [557]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [558]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [559]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [560]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [561]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [562]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [563]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [564]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [565]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [566]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [567]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [568]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [569]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [570]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [571]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠈' [572]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠘' [573]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠸' [574]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⢸' [575]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⣸' [576]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [577]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [578]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' 
  [579]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [580]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [581]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [582]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [583]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [584]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [585]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [586]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [587]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [588]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [589]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [590]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [591]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [592]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [593]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [594]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [595]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [596]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [597]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [598]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [599]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠈' [600]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠘' [601]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠸' [602]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⢸' [603]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⣸' [604]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⢀⣸' [605]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [606]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [607]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [608]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [609]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [610]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [611]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [612]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [613]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [614]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [615]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [616]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [617]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [618]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [619]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [620]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [621]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [622]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [623]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [624]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [625]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [626]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' 
  [627]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠈' [628]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠘' [629]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠸' [630]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⢸' [631]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⣸' [632]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⢀⣸' [633]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⣀⣸' [634]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [635]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [636]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [637]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [638]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [639]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [640]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [641]=$'\E[A⡀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [642]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [643]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [644]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [645]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [646]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [647]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [648]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⢀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [649]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [650]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [651]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [652]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [653]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [654]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [655]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠈' [656]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠘' [657]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠸' [658]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⢸' [659]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⣸' [660]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⢀⣸' [661]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⣀⣸' [662]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠁⢀⣀⣸' [663]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [664]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [665]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [666]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [667]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [668]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [669]=$'\E[A⡀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [670]=$'\E[A⡄⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [671]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [672]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [673]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [674]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' 
  [675]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [676]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⢠\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [677]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [678]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [679]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [680]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [681]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [682]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [683]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠈' [684]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠘' [685]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠸' [686]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⢸' [687]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⣸' [688]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⢀⣸' [689]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⣀⣸' [690]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠃⢀⣀⣸' [691]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠁⣀⣀⣸' [692]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [693]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [694]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [695]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [696]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [697]=$'\E[A⡈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [698]=$'\E[A⡄⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [699]=$'\E[A⡆⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [700]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [701]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [702]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [703]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [704]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⢰\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [705]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢠\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [706]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢁\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [707]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [708]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [709]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [710]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [711]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡈' [712]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠘' [713]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠸' [714]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⢸' [715]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⣸' [716]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⢀⣸' [717]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⣀⣸' [718]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠇⢀⣀⣸' [719]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠃⣀⣀⣸' [720]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢁⣀⣀⣸' [721]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [722]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' 
  [723]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [724]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [725]=$'\E[A⡉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [726]=$'\E[A⡌⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [727]=$'\E[A⡆⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [728]=$'\E[A⡇⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [729]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [730]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [731]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [732]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⢸\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [733]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢰\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [734]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢡\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [735]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢉\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [736]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [737]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [738]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [739]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣈' [740]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡘' [741]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠸' [742]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⢸' [743]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⣸' [744]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⢀⣸' [745]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⣀⣸' [746]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⡇⢀⣀⣸' [747]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠇⣀⣀⣸' [748]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢃⣀⣀⣸' [749]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣁⣀⣀⣸' [750]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [751]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [752]=$'\E[A⠋⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [753]=$'\E[A⡉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [754]=$'\E[A⡍⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [755]=$'\E[A⡎⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [756]=$'\E[A⡇⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [757]=$'\E[A⡏⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [758]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [759]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [760]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [761]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢸\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [762]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢱\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [763]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢩\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [764]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢙\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [765]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [766]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [767]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣨' [768]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣘' [769]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡸' [770]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⢸' 
  [771]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⣸' [772]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⢀⣸' [773]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⣀⣸' [774]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⢀⣀⣸' [775]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⡇⣀⣀⣸' [776]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢇⣀⣀⣸' [777]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣃⣀⣀⣸' [778]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣅⣀⣀⣸' [779]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [780]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [781]=$'\E[A⡉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [782]=$'\E[A⡌⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [783]=$'\E[A⡆⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [784]=$'\E[A⡇⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [785]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [786]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [787]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [788]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⢸\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [789]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢰\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [790]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢡\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [791]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢉\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [792]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [793]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [794]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [795]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣈' [796]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡘' [797]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠸' [798]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⢸' [799]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⣸' [800]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⢀⣸' [801]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⣀⣸' [802]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⡇⢀⣀⣸' [803]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠇⣀⣀⣸' [804]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢃⣀⣀⣸' [805]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣁⣀⣀⣸' [806]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [807]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [808]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [809]=$'\E[A⡈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [810]=$'\E[A⡄⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [811]=$'\E[A⡆⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [812]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [813]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [814]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [815]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [816]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⢰\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [817]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢠\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [818]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢁\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' 
  [819]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [820]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [821]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [822]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [823]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡈' [824]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠘' [825]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠸' [826]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⢸' [827]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⣸' [828]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⢀⣸' [829]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⣀⣸' [830]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠇⢀⣀⣸' [831]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠃⣀⣀⣸' [832]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢁⣀⣀⣸' [833]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [834]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [835]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [836]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [837]=$'\E[A⡀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [838]=$'\E[A⡄⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [839]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [840]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [841]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [842]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [843]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [844]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⢠\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [845]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [846]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [847]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [848]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [849]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [850]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [851]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠈' [852]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠘' [853]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠸' [854]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⢸' [855]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⣸' [856]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⢀⣸' [857]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⣀⣸' [858]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠃⢀⣀⣸' [859]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠁⣀⣀⣸' [860]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [861]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [862]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [863]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [864]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [865]=$'\E[A⡀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [866]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' 
  [867]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [868]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [869]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [870]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [871]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [872]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⢀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [873]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [874]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [875]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [876]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [877]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [878]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [879]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠈' [880]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠘' [881]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠸' [882]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⢸' [883]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⣸' [884]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⢀⣸' [885]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⣀⣸' [886]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠁⢀⣀⣸' [887]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [888]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [889]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [890]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [891]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [892]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [893]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [894]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [895]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [896]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [897]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [898]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [899]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [900]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [901]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [902]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [903]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [904]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [905]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [906]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [907]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠈' [908]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠘' [909]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠸' [910]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⢸' [911]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⣸' [912]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⢀⣸' [913]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⣀⣸' [914]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' 
  [915]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [916]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [917]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [918]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [919]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [920]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [921]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [922]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [923]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [924]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [925]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [926]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [927]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [928]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [929]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [930]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [931]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [932]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [933]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [934]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [935]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠈' [936]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠘' [937]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠸' [938]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⢸' [939]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⣸' [940]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⢀⣸' [941]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [942]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [943]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [944]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [945]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [946]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [947]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [948]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [949]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [950]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [951]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [952]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [953]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [954]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [955]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [956]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [957]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [958]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [959]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [960]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [961]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [962]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' 
  [963]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠈' [964]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠘' [965]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠸' [966]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⢸' [967]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⣸' [968]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [969]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [970]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [971]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [972]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [973]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [974]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [975]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [976]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [977]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [978]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [979]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [980]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [981]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [982]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [983]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [984]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [985]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [986]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [987]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [988]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [989]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [990]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [991]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠈' [992]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠘' [993]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠸' [994]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⢸' [995]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [996]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [997]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [998]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [999]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [1000]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [1001]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [1002]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [1003]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [1004]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [1005]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [1006]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [1007]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [1008]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [1009]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [1010]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' 
  [1011]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [1012]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [1013]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [1014]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [1015]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [1016]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [1017]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [1018]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [1019]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠈' [1020]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠘' [1021]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠸' [1022]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [1023]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [1024]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [1025]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [1026]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [1027]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [1028]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [1029]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [1030]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [1031]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [1032]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [1033]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [1034]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [1035]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [1036]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [1037]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [1038]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [1039]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [1040]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [1041]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [1042]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [1043]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [1044]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [1045]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [1046]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [1047]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠈' [1048]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠘' [1049]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [1050]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [1051]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [1052]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [1053]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [1054]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [1055]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [1056]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [1057]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' 
  [1058]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [1059]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [1060]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [1061]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [1062]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [1063]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [1064]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [1065]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [1066]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [1067]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [1068]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [1069]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [1070]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [1071]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [1072]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [1073]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [1074]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [1075]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠈' [1076]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [1077]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [1078]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [1079]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [1080]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [1081]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [1082]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [1083]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [1084]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [1085]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [1086]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [1087]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [1088]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [1089]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [1090]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [1091]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [1092]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [1093]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [1094]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [1095]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [1096]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [1097]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [1098]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [1099]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [1100]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [1101]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [1102]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [1103]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [1104]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' 
  [1105]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [1106]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [1107]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [1108]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [1109]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [1110]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [1111]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [1112]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [1113]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [1114]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [1115]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [1116]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣸' [1117]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [1118]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [1119]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [1120]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [1121]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [1122]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [1123]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [1124]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [1125]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [1126]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [1127]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [1128]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [1129]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [1130]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1131]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [1132]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [1133]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [1134]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [1135]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [1136]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [1137]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [1138]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [1139]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [1140]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [1141]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [1142]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [1143]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣸' [1144]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣰' [1145]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [1146]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [1147]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [1148]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [1149]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [1150]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [1151]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' 
  [1152]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [1153]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [1154]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [1155]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [1156]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [1157]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1158]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1159]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [1160]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [1161]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [1162]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [1163]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [1164]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [1165]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [1166]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [1167]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [1168]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [1169]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [1170]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣸' [1171]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣰' [1172]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣠' [1173]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [1174]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [1175]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [1176]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [1177]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [1178]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [1179]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [1180]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [1181]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [1182]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [1183]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [1184]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1185]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1186]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1187]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [1188]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [1189]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [1190]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [1191]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [1192]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [1193]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [1194]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [1195]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [1196]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [1197]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣸' [1198]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣰' 
  [1199]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣠' [1200]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⣀' [1201]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [1202]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [1203]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [1204]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [1205]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [1206]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [1207]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [1208]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [1209]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [1210]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [1211]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1212]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1213]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1214]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1215]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [1216]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [1217]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [1218]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [1219]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [1220]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [1221]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [1222]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [1223]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [1224]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣸' [1225]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣰' [1226]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣠' [1227]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⣀' [1228]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⡀' [1229]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [1230]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [1231]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [1232]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [1233]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [1234]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [1235]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [1236]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [1237]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [1238]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1239]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1240]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1241]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1242]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1243]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [1244]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [1245]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' 
  [1246]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [1247]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [1248]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [1249]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [1250]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [1251]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣸' [1252]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣰' [1253]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣠' [1254]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⣀' [1255]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⡀' [1256]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⣀⠀' [1257]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [1258]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [1259]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [1260]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [1261]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [1262]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [1263]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [1264]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [1265]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1266]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1267]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1268]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1269]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1270]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1271]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [1272]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [1273]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [1274]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [1275]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [1276]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [1277]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [1278]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣸' [1279]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣰' [1280]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣠' [1281]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⣀' [1282]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⡀' [1283]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⣀⠀' [1284]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⡀⠀' [1285]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [1286]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [1287]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [1288]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [1289]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [1290]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [1291]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [1292]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' 
  [1293]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1294]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1295]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1296]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1297]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1298]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1299]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [1300]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [1301]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [1302]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [1303]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [1304]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [1305]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣸' [1306]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣰' [1307]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣠' [1308]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⣀' [1309]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⡀' [1310]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⣀⠀' [1311]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⡀⠀' [1312]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⣀⠀⠀' [1313]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [1314]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [1315]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [1316]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [1317]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [1318]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [1319]=$'\E[A⡏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1320]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1321]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1322]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1323]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1324]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1325]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⠹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1326]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1327]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [1328]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [1329]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [1330]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [1331]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [1332]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣸' [1333]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣰' [1334]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣠' [1335]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⣀' [1336]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⡀' [1337]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⣀⠀' [1338]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⡀⠀' [1339]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣆⣀⠀⠀' 
  [1340]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⡀⠀⠀' [1341]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [1342]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [1343]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [1344]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [1345]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [1346]=$'\E[A⡏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1347]=$'\E[A⠏⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1348]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1349]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1350]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1351]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1352]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⠙\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1353]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⠹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1354]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1355]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [1356]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [1357]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [1358]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' [1359]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣸' [1360]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣰' [1361]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣠' [1362]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⣀' [1363]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⡀' [1364]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⣀⠀' [1365]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⡀⠀' [1366]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣄⣀⠀⠀' [1367]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣆⡀⠀⠀' [1368]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣇⠀⠀⠀' [1369]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [1370]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [1371]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [1372]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [1373]=$'\E[A⡏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1374]=$'\E[A⠏⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1375]=$'\E[A⠉⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1376]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1377]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1378]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1379]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⠉\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1380]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⠙\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1381]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠹\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1382]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢸\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1383]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [1384]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [1385]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [1386]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢸' 
  [1387]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣰' [1388]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣠' [1389]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⣀' [1390]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⡀' [1391]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⣀⠀' [1392]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⡀⠀' [1393]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣀⣀⠀⠀' [1394]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣄⡀⠀⠀' [1395]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣆⠀⠀⠀' [1396]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡇⠀⠀⠀' [1397]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [1398]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [1399]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [1400]=$'\E[A⡇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1401]=$'\E[A⠏⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1402]=$'\E[A⠉⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1403]=$'\E[A⠈⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1404]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1405]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1406]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⠁\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1407]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⠉\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1408]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠙\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1409]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠸\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1410]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢰\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1411]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [1412]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [1413]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠸' [1414]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢰' [1415]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣠' [1416]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⣀' [1417]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⡀' [1418]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⣀⠀' [1419]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⡀⠀' [1420]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⢀⣀⠀⠀' [1421]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣀⡀⠀⠀' [1422]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣄⠀⠀⠀' [1423]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡆⠀⠀⠀' [1424]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠇⠀⠀⠀' [1425]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [1426]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [1427]=$'\E[A⡆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1428]=$'\E[A⠇⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1429]=$'\E[A⠉⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1430]=$'\E[A⠈⠁⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1431]=$'\E[A⠀⠉⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1432]=$'\E[A⠀⠈⠁⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1433]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠉⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' 
  [1434]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠈⠁\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1435]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠉\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1436]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠘\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1437]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠰\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1438]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢠\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1439]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⢀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠈' [1440]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠘' [1441]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠰' [1442]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⢠' [1443]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⣀' [1444]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⢀⡀' [1445]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⣀⠀' [1446]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⢀⡀⠀' [1447]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⣀⠀⠀' [1448]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⢀⡀⠀⠀' [1449]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⣀⠀⠀⠀' [1450]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⡄⠀⠀⠀' [1451]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠆⠀⠀⠀' [1452]=$'\E[A⠀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠃⠀⠀⠀' [1453]=$'\E[A⡀⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠁⠀⠀⠀' [1454]=$'\E[A⡄⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀' [1455]=$'\E[A⠆⠀⠀⠀\E[B\E[4D⠀⠀⠀⠀')
```

then:

```
mySpinner() {
    printf '\n%s\e7' "$*"
    while ! read -sn 1 -t .02 _;do
        printf '\e8%s ' ${shapes[shcnt++%${#shapes[@]}]}
    done
    echo
}
mySpinner "Simple test: "
             ⡏⠉⠀⠀
Simple test: ⣇⣀⠀⠀
```

[image: snake spinner braille sample]

### Some explanations

We have 28 *pixels* around a square of  `8 x 8`. building a *shape array*, growing from `1` to `27`, making a full loop with each length, then shrinking from `26` to `2` in order to loop correctly, we must obtain: `( 27 + 25 ) * 28 = 1456` *`shapes`*.

Here is how look 2 1st shapes:

```
[0]=$'\e[A\U2801\U2800\U2800\U2800\e[B\e[4D\U2800\U2800\U2800\U2800'
[1]=$'\e[A\U2808\U2800\U2800\U2800\e[B\e[4D\U2800\U2800\U2800\U2800'
```

As shape use two lines, I use ANSI escape sequences for *moving cursor*:

- `\e[A` : Move cursor up
- `\e[B` : Move cursor down
- `\e[D` : Move cursor left (`\e[4D` move 4 position left)
- In order to ensure correct placement even using non monospace font, whitespace are drawn by using `BRAILLE PATTERN BLANK`  (`\U2800`)

### My question:

What's the shortest way to populate `$shapes` array.

The goal of this is to build the array of 1456 shapes, for a 8x8 square... **But even** if user want a smaller square, I think, the ideal tool must accept as optional argument, an integer, between 2 to 8, specifying the size of desired square!

So in fine.

- The tool could be written in any language,
- If no argument are given, the tool must compute a *progessive snake* around a 8x8 square
- The snake

  - Start at upper left corner with 1 pixel,
  - Do a full turn around desired size square starting horizontally,
  - Grown by 1 pixel at begin of each new turn, upto full size - 1 pixel, then
  - shrink by 1 pixed at begin of each new turn, upto 2 pixel.
- If argument between 2 to 8 are given, the tool must compute a *progessive snake* around a (smaller) square of given size.
- The output could be

  - A full bash array, as cited sample,
  - space separated
  - new line separated
- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shorter code win.

### About [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and final test.

Answering [@Jonah's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/261468/my-eight-braille-pattern-progressive-snake-spinner#comment574689_261468), I use bash for everything, so having a *`shape array`* for playing under bash while other task are running in background seem usefull. ( Playing with backgroud tasks are my every day work! You could have a look at my [Practical GNU/Linux sample 2: sha1sum with progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68298090/1765658) (near bottom of answer).

#### Final script to test *any language* tool:

First a little test function whith:

```bash
mySpinner() {
    local delay=.003 shcnt
    [[ $1 == -d ]] && delay=$2 && shift 2
    printf '\n%s\e[A\e7' "$*"
    while ! read -sn 1 -t $delay _; do
        printf '\e8%s ' ${shapes[shcnt%${#shapes[@]}]}
        ((shcnt++ > ${#shapes[@]}*3/2)) && break 2
    done
    echo
}
```

```
Usage:
    mySpinner [-d delay] [prompt string]
```

Use `$shapes` array to be populated by:

```
mapfile < <(./buildBrailleSnakeSpinner)
```

or

```
mapfile < <(./buildBrailleSnakeSpinner 6)
```

Then

```
mapfile < <(./braille-matrix.sh 7)
mySpinner 'Demo: '
mySpinner -d .05 'Slowed: '
```

## Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=261468;
var OVERRIDE_USER=0;
var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;function answersUrl(d){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+d+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(d,e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+e.join(";")+"/comments?page="+d+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(d){answers.push.apply(answers,d.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],d.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var f=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(f),answers_hash[f]=e}),d.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(d){d.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),d.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=function(){var d=String.raw`h\d`,e=String.raw`\-?\d+\.?\d*`,f=String.raw`[^\n<>]*`,g=String.raw`<s>${f}</s>|<strike>${f}</strike>|<del>${f}</del>`,h=String.raw`[^\n\d<>]*`,j=String.raw`<[^\n<>]+>`;return new RegExp(String.raw`<${d}>`+String.raw`\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?`+String.raw`(${e})`+String.raw`(?=`+String.raw`${h}`+String.raw`(?:(?:${g}|${j})${h})*`+String.raw`</${d}>`+String.raw`)`)}(),OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;function getAuthorName(d){return d.owner.display_name}function process(){var d=[];answers.forEach(function(n){var o=n.body;n.comments.forEach(function(q){OVERRIDE_REG.test(q.body)&&(o="<h1>"+q.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var p=o.match(SCORE_REG);p&&d.push({user:getAuthorName(n),size:+p[2],language:p[1],link:n.share_link})}),d.sort(function(n,o){var p=n.size,q=o.size;return p-q});var e={},f=1,g=null,h=1;d.forEach(function(n){n.size!=g&&(h=f),g=n.size,++f;var o=jQuery("#answer-template").html();o=o.replace("{{PLACE}}",h+".").replace("{{NAME}}",n.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",n.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",n.size).replace("{{LINK}}",n.link),o=jQuery(o),jQuery("#answers").append(o);var p=n.language;p=jQuery("<i>"+n.language+"</i>").text().toLowerCase(),e[p]=e[p]||{lang:n.language,user:n.user,size:n.size,link:n.link,uniq:p}});var j=[];for(var k in e)e.hasOwnProperty(k)&&j.push(e[k]);j.sort(function(n,o){return n.uniq>o.uniq?1:n.uniq<o.uniq?-1:0});for(var l=0;l<j.length;++l){var m=jQuery("#language-template").html(),k=j[l];m=m.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",k.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",k.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",k.size).replace("{{LINK}}",k.link),m=jQuery(m),jQuery("#languages").append(m)}}
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list{padding:10px;float:left}#language-list{padding:10px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/primary.css?v=f52df912b654"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">{{SIZE}}</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">{{SIZE}}</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: If the size is less than 8: 1) Should the output be optimized to use as few Braille characters as possible? Or is the output always 8x8 pixels? 2) Should the snake be positioned in a specific way in the grid? (bottom-left aligned, centered, ...)

Comment: @Arnauld As I don't see how this *output optimization* could shorten the code and as this is a code golf, This is not required. As there is no limitation in question about this, I would agree!

Comment: @Arnaud And yes, I think: As there is no mention of centering or offset, you could locate smaller square wherever you want.

Comment: to be clear, this is a question specifically for bash?

Comment: @Jonah No, The goal is to build the array of shapes. The returned datas could be a bash array, a line separated lst  or even a space separated list of shapes. [tag:bash] routine could be used to play animation. But it's not required

Comment: @Jonah I've edited my question regarding your comment. Have a look at [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/261590/9424), you could replace `bash` by any other scripting interpreter,

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 371 bytes

```javascript
n=process.argv[2]-1||7,i=[],b=[],[x=y=0,1,2,3].map(d=>[...Array(n)].map(_=>(i.push(y&4|x>>1),b.push(1<<(y%4>2?x%2+6:y%4+x%2*3)),d>2?y--:d>1?x--:d?y++:x++))),n*=4,[...Array(n*2-4)].map((_,l)=>[...Array(n)].map((s=Array(8).fill(10240),p)=>([...Array(l+1<n?l+1:n*2-3-l)].map(_=>s[i[p%n]]|=b[p++%n]),console.log(String.fromCharCode(...s).replace(/..../,"$&\x1b[4D\x1b[B")))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDLboMwEPyXqIlsbBwMqK0QBrXpH/Toosg8QqgcY9lpBBL/Tk2plB66h93Z2dG@PsVN2Mp0@uqrvm7mWTFt@qqxlgjT3nhY@HSannDHeIHLxfGBjSzAFIc4KshFaFCzjBNCXowRI1BwJY8sAx3RX/YMxl08DVlGIS5XgqYpGLdxFubDNkSPicPIIS@CENeOHX0/qTOaD0vMR4SSASHoispjMf4zywv9@HceOGIJ/1sEWLYSz5CcOikBDcI4gFg7NbjLJaKpyp1Plq6RL@93WN5xvVVFMbGSa4QchLjqle1lQ2Tfgver6VRLTqa/HM7CHNwjgWtsITGNlqJqwN6lZI83D7uPgZY8fvsJrxu42Dx/Aw) Explanation: Full program that outputs each shape on its own line.

```javascript
n=process.argv[2]-1||7,
```

Get the desired size, but subtract 1.

```javascript
i=[],b=[],[x=y=0,1,2,3].map(d=>[...Array(n)].map(_=>(i.push(y&4|x>>1),b.push(1<<(y%4>2?x%2+6:y%4+x%2*3)),d>2?y--:d>1?x--:d?y++:x++))),
```

For each pixel on the edge of the desired square, calculate the character offset and bitmask that will turn on that Braille dot.

```javascript
n*=4,
```

Get the perimeter of the square.

```javascript
[...Array(n*2-4)].map((_,l)=>
```

Loop over the lengths.

```javascript
[...Array(n)].map((s=Array(8).fill(10240),p)=>
```

Loop around the perimeter.

```javascript
([...Array(l+1<n?l+1:n*2-3-l)].map(_=>s[i[p%n]]|=b[p++%n]),
```

Set the desired Braille dots.

```javascript
console.log(String.fromCharCode(...s).replace(/..../,"$&\x1b[4D\x1b[B")))))
```

Output the resultant string but with the cursor movements in the middle.

Comment: Full test: `for((l=1;++l<9;)){ shapes=($(nodejs brMx-Neil.js $l));printf '\n\e[A';mySpinner "$l: ";}` - Work fine!!

Answer (score 0):

## [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 880 bytes

For making this script truncated at 80 characters by line, I've added some unuseful... this could be reduced be at least 4 characters...

```bash
a=(01 [1]=08 [10]=02 [11]=10 [20]=04  [21]=20 [30]=40 [31]=80);P(){ printf -v "\
$@";};for((i=0;i<8;i++)){ for((l=0;l<8;l++)){ P r %*s $[7-i/4*4-l/2];P r "%*s%s\
" $[2+i/4*4+l/2] ${a[i%4*10+l%2]} "$r";m[$i$l]=$((16#${r// /00}));};};d(){ ((t<=
c||t+n-q-1>++c))&&((r|=m[$1]))&&((++p>=n));};s(){ local -i i w z n q;s=$1;q=(s-1
)*4;local -n r=$2;t=${5:-0};n=${6:-2+q};c=0 p=0;((s>1))&&((s<17))||return;i=(8-s
)/2;u=${3:-$i} v=${4:-$i};for((x=0;x<s;x++)){ w=u+x;d $v$w&&return;};for((x--,y=
1;y<s;y++)){ z=v+y;d $z$w&&return;};for((y--,x--;x>0;x--)){ w=v+x;d $z$w&&return
};for((;y>0;y--)){ z=v+y;d $z$u&&return;};};L() { P d %016X $1;printf "%b%b%b%b\
\e[B\e[4D%b%b%b%b\n" \\U28{${d:0:2},${d:2:2},${d:4:2},${d:6:2},${d:8:2},${d:10:2
},${d:12:2},${d:14}};};b=${1:-8};for((i=1;i<(b-1)*8-3;i++)){ l=$((i>(b-1)*4-1?(b
-1)*8-2-i:i));for((h=0;h<(b-1)*4;h++)){ j=0;s $b j 0 0 $h $l;L $j;};}
```

Sample:

```bash
shapes=($(bash <<"eof"
a=(01 [1]=08 [10]=02 [11]=10 [20]=04  [21]=20 [30]=40 [31]=80);P(){ printf -v "\
$@";};for((i=0;i<8;i++)){ for((l=0;l<8;l++)){ P r %*s $[7-i/4*4-l/2];P r "%*s%s\
" $[2+i/4*4+l/2] ${a[i%4*10+l%2]} "$r";m[$i$l]=$((16#${r// /00}));};};d(){ ((t<=
c||t+n-q-1>++c))&&((r|=m[$1]))&&((++p>=n));};s(){ local -i i w z n q;s=$1;q=(s-1
)*4;local -n r=$2;t=${5:-0};n=${6:-2+q};c=0 p=0;((s>1))&&((s<17))||return;i=(8-s
)/2;u=${3:-$i} v=${4:-$i};for((x=0;x<s;x++)){ w=u+x;d $v$w&&return;};for((x--,y=
1;y<s;y++)){ z=v+y;d $z$w&&return;};for((y--,x--;x>0;x--)){ w=v+x;d $z$w&&return
};for((;y>0;y--)){ z=v+y;d $z$u&&return;};};L() { P d %016X $1;printf "%b%b%b%b\
\e[B\e[4D%b%b%b%b\n" \\U28{${d:0:2},${d:2:2},${d:4:2},${d:6:2},${d:8:2},${d:10:2
},${d:12:2},${d:14}};};b=${1:-8};for((i=1;i<(b-1)*8-3;i++)){ l=$((i>(b-1)*4-1?(b
-1)*8-2-i:i));for((h=0;h<(b-1)*4;h++)){ j=0;s $b j 0 0 $h $l;L $j;};}
eof
))
echo $'\n\e[A\e7';while ! read -sn1 -t .01 _;do
    printf '\e8%b ' ${shapes[shcnt++%${#shapes[@]}]};done
```

```
⡏⠀⠀⠀
⣇⣀⣀⣰
```

or

```bash
mySpinner() { local d=.003 c;[[ $1 == -d ]]&&d=$2&&shift 2;printf \
'\n%s\e[A\e7' "$*";while ! read -sn 1 -t $d _;do printf '\e8%s ' ${shapes[c%
${#shapes[@]}]};((c++>${#shapes[@]}*3/2))&&break 2;done;echo;}

for((l=1;++l<9;)){ 
    shapes=($(bash /dev/stdin <<"eof" $l
a=(01 [1]=08 [10]=02 [11]=10 [20]=04  [21]=20 [30]=40 [31]=80);P(){ printf -v "\
$@";};for((i=0;i<8;i++)){ for((l=0;l<8;l++)){ P r %*s $[7-i/4*4-l/2];P r "%*s%s\
" $[2+i/4*4+l/2] ${a[i%4*10+l%2]} "$r";m[$i$l]=$((16#${r// /00}));};};d(){ ((t<=
c||t+n-q-1>++c))&&((r|=m[$1]))&&((++p>=n));};s(){ local -i i w z n q;s=$1;q=(s-1
)*4;local -n r=$2;t=${5:-0};n=${6:-2+q};c=0 p=0;((s>1))&&((s<17))||return;i=(8-s
)/2;u=${3:-$i} v=${4:-$i};for((x=0;x<s;x++)){ w=u+x;d $v$w&&return;};for((x--,y=
1;y<s;y++)){ z=v+y;d $z$w&&return;};for((y--,x--;x>0;x--)){ w=v+x;d $z$w&&return
};for((;y>0;y--)){ z=v+y;d $z$u&&return;};};L() { P d %016X $1;printf "%b%b%b%b\
\e[B\e[4D%b%b%b%b\n" \\U28{${d:0:2},${d:2:2},${d:4:2},${d:6:2},${d:8:2},${d:10:2
},${d:12:2},${d:14}};};b=${1:-8};for((i=1;i<(b-1)*8-3;i++)){ l=$((i>(b-1)*4-1?(b
-1)*8-2-i:i));for((h=0;h<(b-1)*4;h++)){ j=0;s $b j 0 0 $h $l;L $j;};}
eof
    ))
    mySpinner "Test $l: "
}
```

```
        ⠚⠀⠀⠀
Test 2: ⠀⠀⠀⠀ 
        ⠮⠇⠀⠀
Test 3: ⠀⠀⠀⠀ 
        ⣎⣹⠀⠀
Test 4: ⠀⠀⠀⠀ 
        ⡎⠉⡇⠀
Test 5: ⠉⠉⠁⠀ 
        ⡎⠉⢹⠀
Test 6: ⠓⠒⠚⠀ 
        ⡎⠉⠉⡇
Test 7: ⠧⠤⠤⠇ 
        ⡎⠉⠉⢹
Test 8: ⣇⣀⣀⣸
```